# Closures does not work correctly in the loops

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

I'm try to make a function `getDelete()` that will **create onclick Events** for deleting elements `text` and `pointDel`. The last will be created and included by a support function `createPoindetDel()` for creating   3 elements `pointDel`.

I have try a several ways to solve this problem, but still does not have a right result. My function result still being **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined** wile I want to delete more than one block.

I think the problem in the closures of both functions.

P.S.
I must use these structure. I can not simplify it.

```js
function createPoindetDel(text) {

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) (function(i) {

   var textCoords = text[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 

 var pointDel = document.createElement('p');
            pointDel.innerHTML = '[x]';
     pointDel.className = 'deleting';
     pointDel.style.top = textCoords.top + pageYOffset + 'px';
     pointDel.style.left = textCoords.right + pageXOffset + 'px';
    
 text[i].appendChild(pointDel);

 return pointDel;
    })(i);  
}

function getDelete() {

    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-block');
       
    createPoindetDel(text); 

    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('deleting');

    for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++ ) (function(j) {
    
   p[j].addEventListener( 'click', function() {text[j].remove()} );
 p[j].addEventListener( 'click', function() {p[j].remove()} ); 
 
    })(j);
}

getDelete();
```

```css
.text-block {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px #C4DF9B solid;
  background-color: #EDF5E1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text-block span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:  #111;
  margin-top: 0;
}

 .text-block p {
  font-size:  15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #111;

}

.deleting {
   position:absolute;
   float:right;
   margin:0px;
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
   display:inline;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Horse</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Pig</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
  <div class="text-block">
  <span>Mul</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a event listener to your 'p' element, you do it using an index:

```
p[j].addEventListener( 'click', function() {text[j].remove()} );
// you are accessing the j index from the text array
```

When you delete a element, you change the array's length (text). Right?
Then, when you try to delete another element, you try it using the index defined before, for example index position 2. But the new array has not got an element in position 2.

If you try to click in the last 'x' first, your code will run without problems. Because in this way, you will delete the biggest index.

Its hard to explain. 
But you can try use the event's function scope to resolve:

Edit:
Note that I put **position:relative** in your **.text-block** class, and commented your position hack in JS. This will fix your css too.

Try change your event function like that:

```js
function createPoindetDel(text) {

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) (function(i) {

    var textCoords = text[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 
    var pointDel = document.createElement('p');
  
    pointDel.innerHTML = '[x]';
    pointDel.className = 'deleting';
    //pointDel.style.top = textCoords.top + pageYOffset + 'px';
    //pointDel.style.left = textCoords.right + pageXOffset + 'px';
   
    text[i].appendChild(pointDel);

    //return pointDel;
  })(i);  
}

function getDelete() {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-block');
  createPoindetDel(text); 
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName('deleting');

  for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++ ) (function(j) {
    p[j].addEventListener( 'click', function() {
      //here 'this' is the element that was clicked, and parentElement you can supose! =)
      this.parentElement.remove() 
    });
  })(j);
}

getDelete();
```

```css
.text-block {
  position:relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px #C4DF9B solid;
  background-color: #EDF5E1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text-block span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:  #111;
  margin-top: 0;
}

 .text-block p {
  font-size:  15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #111;

}

.deleting {
   position:absolute;
   float:right;
   margin:0px;
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
   display:inline;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Horse</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Pig</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
  <div class="text-block">
  <span>Mul</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation! And for your help! It's a very helpful case for me! )

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here, not related to closure actually.

1. You are removing the text element, inside the text element you have the ".delete" element.
2. You are trying to hang on to array pointer which is changing. (once removed the array will change, but you are still trying to remove j=2 for example which does not exist in the array - because it has only 2 elements)

Below code will fix these issues, but you will have to deal with the CSS which you made fixed.

```js
function createPoindetDel(text) {

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) (function(i) {

   var textCoords = text[i].getBoundingClientRect(); 

 var pointDel = document.createElement('p');
            pointDel.innerHTML = '[x]';
     pointDel.className = 'deleting';
     pointDel.style.top = textCoords.top + pageYOffset + 'px';
     pointDel.style.left = textCoords.right + pageXOffset + 'px';
    
 text[i].appendChild(pointDel);

 return pointDel;
    })(i);  
}

function getDelete() {

    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-block');
       
    createPoindetDel(text); 

    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('deleting');

    for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++ ) (function(j) {
    
   p[j].addEventListener( 'click', function() {this.parentElement.remove()});
 //p[j].addEventListener( 'click', function() {p[j].remove()} ); 
 
    })(j);
}

getDelete();
```

```css
.text-block {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px #C4DF9B solid;
  background-color: #EDF5E1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text-block span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:  #111;
  margin-top: 0;
}

 .text-block p {
  font-size:  15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #111;

}

.deleting {
   position:absolute;
   float:right;
   margin:0px;
   top: 0;
   right: -20px;
   display:inline;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Horse</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="text-block">
  <span>Pig</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>
  <div class="text-block">
  <span>Mul</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
 </div>

<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be simplify a bit:

```js
function getDelete() {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text-block');
  var pointDel;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    pointDel = document.createElement('div');
    pointDel.innerHTML = '[x]';
    pointDel.className = 'deleting';
    pointDel.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var text = this.parentNode;
      text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
    });
    text[i].appendChild(pointDel);
  }
}

getDelete();
```

```css
.text-block {
  color: #111;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 2px #C4DF9B solid;
  background: #EDF5E1;
  position: relative;
}

.text-block span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-block p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.deleting {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-block">
  <span>Horse</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
</div>
<div class="text-block">
  <span>Pig</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
</div>
<div class="text-block">
  <span>Mul</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not simplify structure. I must use including function structure.